# Are prefixes, as bound morphemes, always separable from their root words?

Tags: prefixes

The root words in the examples below look fine even without a prefix:

> un + **bearable**
>   ir + **regular**
>   dis + **able**
>   mis + **fortune**

... but not in these:

> pro + **gress**
>   pro + **mote**

Possibly, I don't understand what a prefix really is. **–pro** in the above two examples may or may not be a prefix at all. But I would like to have these two points clarified.

1) Is it not always possible to separate a prefix from its root word because doing so will cause the root word lose all meaning?

2) Is it alright to look at **–pro** as a prefix in the above two cases because it's a prefix anyway and being detachable from its root word is not really a criteria for it to be a prefix?

Please discuss.

Comment: A root is a morpheme. There is no requirement for a root to exist in a language as a word on its own.

Comment: All of the prefixes you mention are [Derivational](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Derivation-Inflection.pdf); derivational affixes don't usually have well-defined meanings. Some do, but most don't. And many Englich derivational prefixes and roots were borrowed from Latin or French, **after** the prefixes had been added; and we often didn't borrow the root, only the prefixed words, like _conceive, receive, deceive, perceive._

Answer (score 2):

Prefixes are morphemes that are attached to root terms to create a new or more complex concept.  However, the root term can have many variations, and a given word that contains a prefix may not make sense if the prefix is removed.

Your example of *promote* is one of these. The following is the explanation of the etymology of *[promote](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/promote?view=uk)* from the Compact OED

> late Middle English: from Latin promot- 'moved forward', from the verb promovere, from pro- 'forward, onward' + movere 'to move'

Many prefixes were already attached in the language from which the word derived. This is an example.  *Movere* (to move) is the root and *pro-* (forward) is the prefix. *Promovere* was an acceptable term in Latin before it migrated to Middle English and modern English.

Some of the derivative words in English can stand alone when the prefix is removed, such as *promotion* (pro + motion = forward + movement).

Even if the word was created in modern English by adding a prefix to a root, the variations on the word may not allow the root part to stand alone when the prefix is removed. For example, *telephony* is a term that was created in modern English. If the *tele* ([distance](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tele-)) prefix is removed, the root part *phony* cannot stand alone. However in *telephonic*, when you remove the prefix, *phonic* can stand alone.

Comment: Interesting. So, how does one explain the case of _'promote'_? Should we just say _–pro_ is the prefix and _'mote'_ is the root word without any meaning of its own? In that case, the prefix seems to carry more meaning than the root term it is to supplement.

Comment: *Mote* is a variant, just like *motion* of an underlying Latin root.  *Mote* does not stand alone, but it still conveys the concept of *move*. The prefix does have meaning, but so does the root.

Comment: Would it be completely wrong to say that _–pro_ in words such as _promote_ and _progress_  is not really a prefix but instead an integral part of the word structure. There has to be a technical distinction between words like these where the root term cannot function on its own without the prefix and words where it can (ex: _promotion_, _prolong_ etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Combinations of letters that precede other letters of a word but are integral to the word (i.e., if these first letters are omitted, the remaining letters are meaningless) are called combined forms.  See http://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/prefixes-suffixes-list/

Comment: Really good and helpful information, but as it is not a direct answer to the question as asked, it should probably have been offered in a comment. But given you even offered a citation, and a little reflection on this post *does* answer the question, I'm also happy with it as it is.